# How to run Data Loader using ANT on the server

Tags: data-loader, ant

I have a Data import and export process being carried out by the ANT tool scheduled to run daily from a Desktop.But the issue is when desktop gets auto updates it restarts and scheduled tasks will go off. Is there any way by using tool or plugin available from salesforce to accomplish the same from a server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Ant or the Data Loader *on the salesforce server*. I would recommend taking a look at [Heroku](https://heroku.com) or [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) for a low-cost server that can perform the tasks for you (or other cloud compute services, of course), or you might look into writing some [Batchable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_database_batchable.htm) Apex Code to perform your imports and exports; however, without knowing more about what you're trying to do, I can't tell you which would be more effective.